# Can you prevent the fancyBox navigation areas from occluding media controls?

Tags: jquery, video, navigation, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm using fancyBox 2.1.5 and the included media helper to display and navigate Vimeo videos.

Everything works great except that the Next and Previous clickable areas occlude the video controls at the bottom. Here's a picture with the Next area highlighted.

[image: fancyBox Next]

As you can see, you would not be able to adjust the volume, switch to fullscreen, or manipulate the progress bar underneath this area.

I'm aware that the navigation arrows can be placed on the outside of the presentation area, but it reduces display real estate on mobile devices, so I'd rather not.

Is it possible to prevent these clickable areas from extending all the way to the bottom when showing videos? Or maybe another solution I haven't considered?

Comment: Check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful No.5

Comment: Thanks JFK, but as I mentioned, I'm hoping to avoid that solution, if possible.

Comment: then use the button helper and disable the normal navigation arrows `arrows:false`

Comment: Thanks - also an alternative - but I would still ideally like to use the internal navigation buttons to save space on smaller devices. I also just think they're kinda slick :P. Not a dealbreaker if it can't be done, but still throwing it out there in case it's possible to adjust those internal button dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution! Turns out the navigation block in jquery.fancybox.css contains a `top` offset and a `height` parameter!

Keeping `top: 0` and setting `height: 90%` leaves a 10% gap at the bottom of the frame, allowing you to interact with video controls! Here's the entire block I added to my website's css:

```
/* Prevent navigation from occluding play controls for videos */
.fancybox-type-iframe .fancybox-nav {
    height: 90%;
}
```

Being a percentage, it's possible if you have a short, very wide video, 90% coverage will still eat into the video controls, but this has so far worked well for standard video dimensions like 720p.